# Keep a running total in Angular's ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a hard time getting the result that I'm looking for. Here is an image of my table row.[image]

The final column (the one circled in blue) is support to count that mini-tables (Quantity - Allocated - Reserved) then subtracts the number in orange (in this case -4).

I can get the first row to work (for example, it shows 1, which is correct). But the second row should be accumulative, so that it adds the blue number from the previous row. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Angular.

This is my view template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="inbound in inventory.inbound">
  <td><% inbound.fordate %></td>
  <td><% inbound.quantity %></td>
  <td><% inbound.allocated %></td>
  <td><input type="number" ng-model="inbound.reserved" ng-change="submitChangedInbound()" class="inbound_reserved"></td>
  <td><span class="label round" ><% availableAfterShipment() %></span</td>
</tr>
```

and this is my function:

```
$scope.availableAfterShipment = function(amount) {
  return $scope.dealerAvailable + this.inbound.quantity - this.inbound.allocated - this.inbound.reserved;
};
```

Comment: wouldnt the first row be 3-(-4) = 7, instead of 1?